# Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to run a simple powershell script as a post build windows powershell step. 
    the command I have given is powershell -File test.ps1. 
    the test.ps1 file has a simple write-host that says: Write-Host "Hello how are you doing"
    the build is a maven project and runs fine with out the inclusion of the windows powershell post step. However, with the inclusion of the powershell script it fails and throws the following error-

```
         [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Jenkins\workspace\WLR3\pom.xml to aBILLity/NxTier/1.0-SNAPSHOT/NxTier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
            [WLR3] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\TEST_R~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins9080398754273983665.ps1'"
            The system cannot find the file specified
            FATAL: command execution failed
            java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
                at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
                at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
            Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell.exe" (in directory "C:\Jenkins\workspace\WLR3"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
                at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
                at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
                at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
                at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
                at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
                at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
                at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
                at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
                at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
                at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:939)
                at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:890)
                at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
                at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1794)
                at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
                at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
                at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
            Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
            channel stopped
```

any help would be much appreciated! 
    thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?  I don't believe Powershell is available by default on all versions of Windows.  What happens when you type "powershell.exe" into a Command Prompt window (on the Jenkins node running the job)?

Comment: Hello there , thanks for the reply. Turned out that the issue was with the execution policy. It was set to remote and upon changing to unrestricted, things started to work .